# apache mod rewrite on a subdirectory

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache

quick question about mod rewriting on a sub-directory when i already have a rewrite rule on the webroot to remove 'index.php'

my .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

i have an API directory (/webroot/api/index.php) where i want to have a RESTful API (Restler) to serve requests into the application- so my question is..

to make RESTful requests i need to use the following URL format:

```
/webroot/api/index.php/user/get/ (to get all the users)
```

what i would like to achieve is something in the form:

```
/webroot/api/user/get/ (return a list of users)
```

which still retaining the base rewrite rules for the main website

```
/webroot/members/  (display a list of users in the main applications)
```

many thanks,
Justen

Answer (score 0):

Your base rewrites look odd.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

This says that if we match `index.php` we are done (and no rewrite takes place). Is that what you want? If the request is exactly for `/index.php` with no trailing material, then it is left alone.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

To **remove** `index.php` you want something like:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) $1 [L]
```

E.g. `index.php/foo` goes to `foo` (relative rewrite: then `RewriteBase` gets tacked on it turning into the `/foo` URL to feed back into the request pipeline.)

Comment: Hi there, what i would like is effectively two rewrite rules.. 1) `if url = /index.php then remove "index.php"` and 2) `if url = /api/index.php then remove "index.php"` .. not sure if this is possible, but it would look much cleaner